# apache nutch 2.2.1 with hbase ERROR

Tags: apache, solr, hbase, nutch

I use Nutch 2.2.1, 4.3.0 and HBase 0.90.4 SOLR.

I get the following error.

```
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore as the Gora storage class.
InjectorJob: total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
InjectorJob: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=generate: null, jobid=job_local1662982347_0002
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:199)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:152)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)
```

In the Hadoop logs is the following.

```
2014-08-11 09:13:43,246 INFO  crawl.InjectorJob - InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore as the Gora storage class.
2014-08-11 09:13:43,293 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2014-08-11 09:13:43,372 WARN  snappy.LoadSnappy - Snappy native library not loaded
2014-08-11 09:13:44,017 INFO  mapreduce.GoraRecordWriter - gora.buffer.write.limit = 10000
2014-08-11 09:13:44,245 INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer - can't find rules for scope 'inject', using default
2014-08-11 09:13:44,381 WARN  mapred.FileOutputCommitter - Output path is null in cleanup
2014-08-11 09:13:44,686 INFO  crawl.InjectorJob - InjectorJob: total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
2014-08-11 09:13:44,686 INFO  crawl.InjectorJob - InjectorJob: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 1
2014-08-11 09:13:44,695 INFO  crawl.FetchScheduleFactory - Using FetchSchedule impl: org.apache.nutch.crawl.DefaultFetchSchedule
2014-08-11 09:13:44,696 INFO  crawl.AbstractFetchSchedule - defaultInterval=2592000
2014-08-11 09:13:44,696 INFO  crawl.AbstractFetchSchedule - maxInterval=7776000
2014-08-11 09:13:45,392 INFO  mapreduce.GoraRecordReader - gora.buffer.read.limit = 10000
2014-08-11 09:13:45,501 INFO  crawl.FetchScheduleFactory - Using FetchSchedule impl: org.apache.nutch.crawl.DefaultFetchSchedule
2014-08-11 09:13:45,501 INFO  crawl.AbstractFetchSchedule - defaultInterval=2592000
2014-08-11 09:13:45,501 INFO  crawl.AbstractFetchSchedule - maxInterval=7776000
2014-08-11 09:13:45,547 INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer - can't find rules for scope 'generate_host_count', using default
2014-08-11 09:13:45,654 INFO  mapreduce.GoraRecordWriter - gora.buffer.write.limit = 10000
2014-08-11 09:13:45,670 WARN  mapred.FileOutputCommitter - Output path is null in cleanup
2014-08-11 09:13:45,671 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1662982347_0002
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.<init>(Utf8.java:37)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:398)
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I have all the things implemented in the book "Web crawling and data mining with Apache Nutch".

Unfortunately coming back error. Currently I am unfortunately Clueless.

Comment: How you solve your problem. I am also facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the line failing:

```
batchId = new Utf8(conf.get(GeneratorJob.BATCH_ID));
```

How are you running your job? If I am not wrong, `crawl` command is deprecated, and now `generate` needs a batch id; at least, it happened to me time ago. Now with a development branch seems to work fine even if you don't set the batch id...

---

From http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial:

> N.B. The crawl command in the bin/nutch script is deprecated. You
>   should use individual commands or alternatively use the bin/crawl
>   script... which effectively chains together individual commands.